# Images stored in a Firebase bucket are not loading in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-storage

**I have a MERN app and I am storing my Images in a firebase bucket**

When I run client and server on diff ports (during development) they are working , but when I build the client , and serve them as static files , it is giving me the following error.

> Refused to load the image 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/My-Bucket-Name.appspot.com/o/images%2FHarry.jpeg?alt=media&token= "some-access-token"' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".

I have set the read and write access of the bucket to public.

Note: It is working during devlopment but getting the error when I serve static files with express.static

I have tried to set the following tag (I got it from chatGPT) in the index.html files of build folder, but it still doesn't work:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that content security policy is directly blocking the images from loading.

Try changing the meta tag to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' firebasestorage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```